# Trouble Fetching Purchase Order Details Via Shopify API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, dataframe, shopify-api

I have been unable to find adequate guidance in the process of fetching **purchase order** details using the Shopify API. This lack of detailed information has hindered my progress significantly.

Could you please provide detailed guidance, documentation, or any available resources to assist me in successfully retrieving purchase order details via the Shopify API? Any support or direction you can offer would be immensely appreciated.

I am eager to address this matter swiftly and would be grateful for your immediate support.

I want to fetch **purchase order** details.

I tried many ways, but Normal orders fetched and when I changed URL can't access the URL error.